# Leadership over smaller churches in early Christianity

Tags: church-history, early-church, ecclesiology, bishops, church-hierarchy

I have heard a claim that during the early Church, bigger churches had leadership positions over smaller churches, which later developed into the idea of a single bishop ruling a dicosese. Are there any examples of this?

Comment: There is no evidence of it in scripture, neither in Acts, nor in the epistles to the churches nor in the epistles to Timothy and Titus. Was any attempt made to substantiate the 'claim' to which you refer ?

Comment: Seconding the request to edit this question to give the claim in question more precision

Comment: I think this Q looks for historical instances of the precursor of Metropolitan bishops recognizable by early 4th century which were in turn the precursor of archbishops recognizable starting in the 7th century until today.  The institution of [monarchical] bishop itself was recognizable since mid 2nd century in the writings of St. Irenaeus of Lyons.  Agree that OP should provide a reference of the claim (so it's more than conjecture) and more precision.

Comment: The "Historical origin" section of the [Catholic encyclopedia entry on Bishop](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02581b.htm) has "The primitive Christian communities were administered by a college of presbyters; those of the presbyters administered the finances were called bishops. In the large towns, the whole financial administration was centralized in the hands of one such officer, who soon became the ruling bishop." which may provide the basis of the claim.

Comment: @SupportiveDante I would prefer you don't change my question lest you try to change it into something I'm not asking about.